# How to add an independent column into a query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to googling for this issue and still couldn't find the solution.
I have 2 column to combine like below:

First table:

```
ID  Name    Item
42  america 1433
42  america 1695
42  america 1234
8   london  1433
8   london  1705
8   london  1432
```

Second table:

```
ID  CreatedBy
42  John
42  Erica
8   Amy Song
8   Alfred
```

If I just join both table it will become like this:

```
ID  Name    Item    CreatedBy
42  america 1433    John
42  america 1695    John
42  america 1234    John
42  america 1433    Erica
42  america 1695    Erica
42  america 1234    Erica
8   london  1433    Amy Song
8   london  1705    Amy Song
8   london  1432    Amy Song
8   london  1433    Alfred
8   london  1705    Alfred
8   london  1432    Alfred
```

Column Created By is only related to ID, and not related to Name and Item.
I just want to insert CreatedBy as a new column into first table that only linked to ID, so the expected result will be like below.
Is there any way I could get result like this?

```
ID  Name    Item    CreatedBy
42  america 1433    John
42  america 1695    Erica
42  america 1234    NULL
8   london  1433    Amy Song
8   london  1705    Alfred
8   london  1432    NULL
```

Let say we change second table like this:

Second table:

```
ID  CreatedBy
42  John
8   Amy Song
```

Result will be like this:

```
ID  Name    Item    CreatedBy
42  america 1433    John
42  america 1695    NULL
42  america 1234    NULL
8   london  1433    Amy Song
8   london  1705    NULL
8   london  1432    NULL
```

I really apreacite for your help, and thank you in advanced masta.

NOTE: Column CreatedBy is the independent column that only relate to ID and not relate to Name and Item.

Comment: What is the logic behind your desired output?  Why are you taking the 1433 with Amy instead of Alfred and vice versa?

Comment: I am puzzled by your question. I assume that ID is a foreign key to another table where the ID field is unique. However, I do not see why the `CreatedBy` value for the last row in your desired result should be `NULL` and why you want **Amy Song** to have `Item` number **1433** when **Alfred** has a record for that `Item`. Could you explain?

Comment: Hi, that's why I said I want to insert the CreatedBy column as independent data that only relate to ID and not relate with Name and Item

Comment: If it's independent data, then what values need to be filled in there? The current set of data seems incomplete to see a distinct pattern.

Comment: You say it's related by ID, but it's not. Because If it's truly related by ID, then the result from the second block is correct. What this means is there's a hidden second relationship that you haven't told us about. The real relationship is ID in addition to something else. And you're using contradictory terms. Something can't be "independent" and also "related".

Comment: The CreatedBy values need to be there to link with ID, so user will know is ID 42 the CreatedBy: John and Erica, and ID 8 CreatedBy: Amy Song and Alfred

Comment: It seems to me the real relationship is ID and row number. In which case, you can use an outer join with a windowed function to do this.

Comment: Hi Jorge Campos, its client requested and I dont have idea to do this.
His Rabbit, if I just join it will duplicate the Name and Item

Comment: Hi Rabbit, any code sample?

Comment: You are missing most of the details required for somebody to be able to offer more than guessing. This would be a great place to start getting an answer. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @user1437001 Hi there! Have you checked my answer?

Comment: Yes bro, you are really great. It's work. My problem is solved.
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I will answer you even though some guys that discussed it here on comments may disagree as there is no a proper logic to your problem.

**It is important to note that this answer is for this SPECIFIC case** if it won't get you the right data for a larger dataset you have to provide more info on it.

What I did:

I've created a subset from the first set ordering it (and indexing it, window function) by the `name` then I created another subset from the second set ordering it by the `id` so, i have:

```
select id, name, item, row_number() over (partition by name order by name) idx from tablea
```

And

```
select id, createdby, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) idx from tableb
```

Then I LEFT JOIN the `tablea` with `tableb` by the `id` and the order created colum `idx` so

```
select a.id, a.name, a.item, b.createdby 
  from (select id, name, item, row_number() over (partition by name order by name) idx from tablea) a
       left join 
       (select id, createdby, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) idx from tableb) b 
              on (a.id = b.id and a.idx=b.idx)
  order by a.name
```

The `order by` is just to get the result as you asked on your question.

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ef70/3

For your second sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/675625/1

Comment: @user1437001 Great to know that it helped! Please consider in accept the answer! It is that "V" on the left side of the answer and below the 0 !